# Display words that do not contain the specified letter

Tags: c++

```
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    string s = "We study C++ programming language first semester.", word;
    cout << s << endl;
    s.pop_back();
    stringstream in (s);

    
    while (in >> word)
    {
        if (word.find('e') == std::string::npos)
        cout << word << endl;            
    }
    
   
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Hello everyone! Given the line **"We study C ++ programming language first semester."** And it is necessary to deduce words from it that do not contain the letter **'e'**.
There is such a version of the program, but I need something simpler without stl.
Using canned loops, etc and preferably using **char**
I will be very grateful to everyone for their help!

Comment: what help do you need? [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: We are not doing your homework, but we can guide you. What's blocking you at the moment ?

Comment: You can't use stdlib?

Comment: btw I suppose you mean the C++ standard library. STL is a library that predates the C++ standard library. And writing C++ code without using C++ wont make your code any simpler

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "something simpler without STL"? Coding in C++ and not using STL in general does not make much sense.

Comment: @pptaszni there are platforms where the standard library is not available (though I suppose OP is rather driven by weird homework requirements)

Comment: @trialNerror, I want to make this program using loops, I don’t understand how to make a loop write words somewhere if there is no letter in them 'e'. And how to split a string char into words

Comment: Write a function that takes a string and a character, and returns a boolean that shows whether the string contains the character. Splitting into words is what `while (in >> word)` does.

Comment: @molbdnilo, can I split it without while( in >> word)??

Comment: Of course you can, but it's pointless to try to say how since you're just going to add another reason for why you can't use exactly that solution.

Comment: @molbdnilo, because I don't really understand how it works while(in >> word).

Comment: *in* is a stringstream, and using the >> operator "parses" the string *s* based on the delimiter which is a white space. Each time the while loop iterates it puts the next set of characters separated by white space into word

Comment: if you can use stringstreams then you can also use C++ STL and so try using vectors they would be easier than stringstream

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you really want to go with only `std::string` and loops, I guess maybe this? But it's a lot longer than just using `stringstream` and such,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "We study C++ programming language first semester.";
    s += ' '; //safeguard;

    std::string word = "";
    for (char c : s)
    {
        if (c == ' ') //break of word
        {
            if (word != "") //word not empty
            {
                bool incE = false;
                for (char c2 : word) //check for e
                {
                    if (c2 == 'e') {incE = true; break;}
                }

                if (!incE)
                {
                    std::cout << word << " ";
                }

                word = "";
            }
        }
        else {word = word + c;}
    }
}
```

Output: `study C++ programming first`